# Docker CE not registered as a service on Debian 9

Tags: debian, docker

I've installed the Docker Community Edition according to the resource: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-debian-9/

However, when I reach step 5 (systemctl status docker) I get the following error message instead of the service status:

```
root@srv-012:/etc/systemd# systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unknown unit: docker.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.service' for details.
```

All commands are run as root. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
The file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` is created correctly, here is the contents:

[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set     required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in     systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Try to Fix your Typos

Comment: Which typos are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, verify that file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` actually exists; if it doesn't, a previous installation step has failed - or the name of the service has changed since the tutorial was written.

Then, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make systemd reload any new unit files. If `systemctl status docker` works after this, you might file a bug report about bad `.deb` packaging - the package should have done that automatically on install.

In the comments it turned out the error message was:

```
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```

This suggests some kind of problem in communication between the `systemctl` command and the `systemd` daemon.

Does `systemctl status` in general work at all?

Are you using some other init system instead of Debian 9 default `systemd`? That Docker package you installed assumes `systemd` is used. Is the `systemd-sysv` package installed?

Comment: Thanks, the file does exist and `systemctl daemon-reload` runs successfully. However, `systemctl status docker` is still failing with this error:
`Failed to get properties: No such interface ''`

Comment: Next thing to check would be the contents of the `docker.service` file.

Comment: Thanks, I added the content of the file, which looks good to me.

Comment: That error message suggests some kind of problem in communication between the `systemctl` command and the `systemd` daemon. Does `systemctl status` in general work at all? Are you using some other init system instead of Debian 9 default `systemd`? That Docker package you installed assumes `systemd` is used. Is the `systemd-sysv` package installed?

Comment: That's it! systemd wasn't used on the server. Thank you very much! Do you want to add that to your answer before I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution.

When I installed docker on debian, I uses `apt`. I first had to add the repository to the sources. But after that I just did an apt-get update and an apt-get install. This is much easier.